# URL rewrite rule that allows long URL to appear shorter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to users to visit:

```
domain.com/example
```

and have the content from the following page displayed:

```
domain.com/directory1/directory2/directory3/example.html
```

In the browser, I would like it to say domain.com/example without redirecting. We have a series of landing pages that need to have short URLs within the domain.

I considered doing something programmatically such as a PHP include however I felt an .htaccess rewrite rule would be best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^example$ /directory1/directory2/directory3/example.html [L]
```

If you want it to work for every file (replacing "example" with any file) then replace the `RewriteRule` line with:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /directory1/directory2/directory3/$1.html [L]
```

Comment: I believe this will solve the problem but I just realized there would be another issue. I'm using a web application that inserts index.php before every URL with the following rule: RewriteRule .* index.php [L] there by trying to process "example" URL through the web app. Is there a condition to bypass it?

Comment: @deeperData You can add the above rule *before* the one that routes to the index.php file. If that doesn't work, then you may need to edit your index.php file or your web application to do this kind of routing

Comment: Indeed, adding it before worked. I tried that before I asked but I left conditions on that were unrelated to this fix and it disabled the index.php rewrite rule. Anyways, you're a gentleman and a saint. Thank you sir.